# Data not displaying in recycler View

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm fairly new to Mobile dev and kotlin in general.
Right now, I'm trying to populate a recyclerview with data from the database.
Issue is, I know the connection is established because I can see the log message on the console

I am not really sure what I'm doing wrong at this point and I don't even understand anymore where is the issue.
I have tried almost every solution I found on here or other websites but nothing worked out.

---

Adapter :

```
class restaurantadapter(private var restaurantList: ArrayList<Restaurant>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<restaurantadapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.restaurant_card_view, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return restaurantList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val restaurant = restaurantList.get(position)
        holder.titleTextView?.text = restaurant.title
        holder.desTextView?.text = restaurant.description
        }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
         var titleTextView: TextView? = null
         var desTextView: TextView? = null

        init {
            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantname)
            desTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantdesc)

        }
    }
```

---

Main activity

```
class Main1Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var restaurantList: ArrayList<Restaurant> = ArrayList()
   private var adapter: restaurantadapter? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1)

        var recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.restaurantslist)
        recyclerView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this@Main1Activity)
        adapter=restaurantadapter(restaurantList,this
        )

        recyclerView.adapter=adapter

      ApiClient.getApiClient()!!.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        ApiClient.apiservice.getRestaurants()
            .enqueue(object: Callback<ArrayList<Restaurant>>{
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ArrayList<Restaurant>>,
                    response: Response<ArrayList<Restaurant>>
                )
                {
                   val response = response.body()
                    response?.let {
                        restaurantList.addAll(it)
                        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Restaurant>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@Main1Activity,"failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })



    }
```

---

layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    app:contentPadding="12dp"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restaurantname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
          />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/restaurantdesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/restaurantname"
            android:textSize="22sp"
             />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of this layout? R.layout.restaurant_card_view

Comment: yes it's added.

Comment: sorry, can't see it. it would be very useful to understand the layout of the single item

Comment: please check again now, I edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you passed empty list `restaurantList` to the adapter and then added the response to this list `restaurantList.addAll(it)` but this will update the list in your activity, not the list in the adapter, to solve this problem you can create method in the adapter to update its list

```
fun updateData(newRestaurant: ArrayList<Restaurant>) {
    restaurantList = newRestaurant
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

The code in `onResponse` will be:

```
val response = response.body()
response?.let {
    adapter.updateData(it)
}
```

Comment: you should move `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` into `updateData` so that the view doesn't have to tell the adapter to change, this is where bugs creep in when you need to call this line every time you change data, but this answer will work

Comment: @a_local_nobody You are right, i will edit it, Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time into answering me, just a quick question, newApples is supposed to be a typo right ? 
yet.. unfortunately I still have the same issue, the data still doesn't display

Comment: @ZahraCarthageCHOUCHENE You are welcome, yes its typo i edited the post now

Comment: thank you very much, however I still have the same issue, it automatically shows me the failure toast message I set, on the failure method.
I'm sorry..

Comment: That means the request itself fails, try to print the error message from the t (Throwable) variable in the log and the response code so we can identify it, to get the message use `t.message` and you can also print the stack track  `t.printStackTrace()`

Comment: the problem was and I'm sorry to say this, but I set the Id as Int whereas it should  have been a string..

Comment: @ZahraCarthageCHOUCHENE Don't be sorry it's normal, everyone faces these errors